# Local Disc (C:) inconsistent size?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Windows 7 tells me that there is ~25GB free in Local Disc (C:) but when I navigate inside, if I select everything and look at properties, the size is different. Take a look at the screenshot to see what I mean.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Any ideas as to why is this happening? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Not everything is included there:

- The contents of the Recycle Bin (C:/$Recycle.Bin ) (4 GB on my system)
- System Restore data (C:/System Volume Information) (20 GB on my system)
- Various other system files.

Tools > Folder Options should have an option to toggle the display of those system files.

Comment: So the "My Computer" window with the size of the Hard Drive in red is the CORRECT size?

Comment: @Hristo: Yes it is.

Comment: all hidden files and system files are visible. inconsistency still present. not sure what is going on. recycle bin is empty.

Comment: How big is the gap now?

Comment: @Macha... so Local Disc says there is about ~170GB being used... but when I do the right-click > properties inside... it says there is about ~50GB being used. all hidden and system files are visible. I did Tools > Folder Options > show hidden files.

Comment: @Hristo Show Hidden files does not display hidden files. There is another option to show "protected system files" also.

Comment: @Macha... well would you be mind telling me what the other option is?

Comment: @Hristo: Uncheck "Hide protected operating system files".

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can see hidden/system files?  It seems like I should see a swap file in your root if  that was enabled but I don't.

Comment: haha... not my computer... I'll have to check that when I look at the computer again. Thanks

Comment: Dude! why did you vote almost all my post down?(even accepted solutions are -1) This is a  community forum design to help each other.

Comment: @djshortbus: If you were bulk downvoted, the system _should_ detect it, and remove it within 48 hours.

Comment: back to the question... yes all hidden/system files are showing. inconsistency still there.

Answer (score 1):

Could also include Data Streams, that aren't shown at all, but are there

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely due to automatic backups and system restore snapshots.

Try disabling Shadow Copies and you should see it go up.